# Common list for a group chat with bot framefork

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, telegram

i want to build simple Telegram bot with Microsoft Bot Framework (C#)
What i'm trying to do now is to create a list that can be filled by everyone in a group chat. The result that i want:

```
user a: /add hello
user b: /add world
user a: /show
bot: hello world
user b: /show
bot: hello world
```

but what i have for now is:

```
user a: /add hello
user b: /add world
user a: /show
bot: hello
user b: /show
bot: world

[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        switch (Parser.GetCommand(activity))
        {
            case "/add":
                AddNewThingToList(activity);
                break;
            case "/show":
                ShowList(context);
                break;
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private void AddNewThingToList(Activity activity)
    {
        list.Add(Parser.GetAfterCommandText(activity));
    }

    private void ShowList(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var response = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            response.Append($"{i}. {list[i]}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        context.PostAsync(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

what is the most simple way to create a common list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need the list in a separate, static list to maintain a single list between all the instances of your root dialog. Something like the following that can be accessed by `RootDialog`:

```
static class ListTest
{
    static List<string> _list; // Static List instance

    static ListTest()
    {
        _list = new List<string>();
    }

    public static void AddNewThingToList(Activity activity)
    {
        _list.Add(Parser.GetAfterCommandText(activity));
    }

    public static void ShowList()
    {
        var response = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
        {
            response.Append($"{i}. {_list[i]}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

There will have to be considerations for multiple readers / writers accessing the list, but the code should get you pointed toward a solution.